# How to check version number of Oracle HTTP Server in Linux?

Tags: httpserver

I am working on Oracle Web Tier components- Oracle Web Cache, Oracle HTTP Server and I am new to these. I need to know which version of Oracle HTTP Server we are having. How/where can I find this?

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to execute the following command:

> httpd.worker -v

Find this httpd file by executing:

> locate httpd

If, when you execute the first command, you get an error message similar to this:

> error while loading shared libraries: libdms2.so: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory

then simply set the following environment variable to the directory which contains the .so file being mentioned:

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/app/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_WT1/lib/

Answer (score 1):

To determine the version of Oracle HTTP Server you have, try the following:

1. Navigate to your `{OHS_INSTANCE}/bin` directory. In this directory, there should be an `httpd` file.

   2. Execute the command: `./httpd -version`

Output will be similar to:

```
Server version:  Oracle-HTTP-Server/2.2.22 (Unix)<br>
Server built:    Mar 23 2015 20:24:40 <br>
Server label:    APACHE_11.1.1.9.0_SOLARIS.X64_150320.1901
```